# What does `BNE #+-20` ARM instruction do?

Tags: assembly, arm

I came across the following instruction when looking at output from a disassembler, running on an OS binary:

```
BNE #+-20
```

I know what the `BNE` instruction does, but I have not been able to find any reference to `+-`.

When Z is non-zero, where will the program counter jump?

Or maybe my disassembler is buggy?

Comment: @CodyGray please see the edit.

Comment: `+-` means the same as in regular math. Adding a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that I've never seen the notation `#+` before; disassemblers I used replaced the argument of relative jump instructions by the destination address.

However I think that `#+X` means: The address of this instruction (or the following one - depending on the architecture) plus `X` bytes (or words).

So `#+-20` means: "The destination address is the address of this instruction minus 20 bytes". (*)

(*) You have to find out if `-20` is relative to the address of the `BNE` instruction itself or to the address of the next instruction and you have to find out if `-20` is the number of bytes or the number of 16- or 32-bit words.